# Javascript string replace Error: Variable is undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace a string like this:

```
var thecurrentURL = 'IAmATextString=12345'
thecurrentURL = thecurrentURL.replace('IAmATextString', '').split('=');
thecurrentURLvalue = thecurrentURL[1];
```

if i alert this like

```
alert(thecurrentURLvalue);
```

it returns the right string. Now i want check if the String is the right one and write it in a div

```
if (thecurrentURLvalue == '12345' ) {
$('#Title').html('12345');
}
```

When i try to check it does not work and returns

```
TypeError: thecurrentURL is undefined     
thecurrentURL = thecurrentURL.replace('IAmATextString', '').split('=');
```

What is the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Are your missing ';' at the end of var thecurrentURL = 'IAmATextString=12345';

Comment: @hicurin wouldn't make a difference, there must be something else wrong here Marc, I don't see any issues

Comment: This seems to work just fine http://jsfiddle.net/mMLU5/ - Are you sure you don't have some extra scopes in your code?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't exhibit any problem. We cannot help you without more information.

Comment: Hm strange. I will provide more code shortly. Please give me a moment to reproduce the problem in a fiddle

Comment: Ok i am sure it has to do with something else in my code. This topic does not make sense i will delete it. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Check following code:

```
var thecurrentURL = 'IAmATextString=12345'
thecurrentURL = thecurrentURL.split('=');//Array Contains ['IAmATextString','12345']
//thecurrentURL.replace('IAmATextString', '').split('=');//Array Contains ['12345'] Index 0 only available here 
thecurrentURLvalue = thecurrentURL[1];
```

please check jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gu9nu/2/)

Comment: Do you mean it should be "thecurrentURL[0];" ? The strange thing is, it returns "12345" when i alert it. But it does not work if i check it with the if condition